# Which part of Go(lang) is in Crystal(lang)?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

Reading [Crystal Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_(programming_language)) They says it is inspired from many programming language and Go.

I would like too know which part of Golang, since it is not its syntax.

Comment: Reference: the original comment about the influence https://crystal-lang.org/2016/06/14/crystal-0.18.0-released.html#comment-2732771703

Comment: This seems off-topic here, unfortunately, as it is not a conceptual question about programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply asked @asterite, one of the developers of Crystal, at IRC #crystal-lang (the log is [here](https://irclog.whitequark.org/crystal-lang/2016-12-22)).

He said the answer is [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), the concurrency model. For example, both Go and Crystal use channels for communications.

Comment: ok ... I have updated the wikipedia page with the crystal reference.

Comment: oh, sorry for my misleading comment. I just wanted to make a reference note for others who have the same question. I think the previous link to Wikipedia is OK :-)

Comment: since it is right ... it need to be on this wikipedia page :-)

Comment: sorry to have not enough reputation to give you a point